# split Json array into two rows spark scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
root
 |-- runKeyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities: string (nullable = true)
```

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|runKeyId|entities                                                                                    |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|1       |{"Partition":[{"Name":"ABC"},{"Name":"DBC"}],"id":339},{"Partition":{"Name":"DDD"},"id":339}|
```

and I would like to explode into this with scala:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|runKeyId|entities                                                                                    |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1       |{"Partition":[{"Name":"ABC"},{"Name":"DBC"}],"id":339}
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2       |{"Partition":{"Name":"DDD"},"id":339}
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: how did you read the file? it looks like jsonl format then you can simply read `spark.read.json("json_path")` automatically separates json to rows.

Comment: Here input i am getting it as a string and not json

Comment: how you are reading the data of input jsons?

Comment: val parseDF = decompressDataDF
      .select($"_1.entities")

Comment: I have provided answer for the similar question here. Please have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63375812/4758823

Comment: @SomeshwarKale you are hardcoding the keys ..it is dynamic in my case

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have a valid JSON, So fix the JSON first and then you can read as JSON and explode it as below.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "{\"Partition\":[{\"Name\":\"ABC\"},{\"Name\":\"DBC\"}],\"id\":339},{\"Partition\":{\"Name\":\"DDD\"},\"id\":339}")
).toDF("runKeyId", "entities")
  .withColumn("entities", concat(lit("["), $"entities", lit("]"))) //fix the json 


val resultDF = df.withColumn("entities",
  explode(from_json($"entities", schema_of_json(df.select($"entities").first().getString(0))))
).withColumn("entities", to_json($"entities"))


resultDF.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|runKeyId|entities                                                        |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|1       |{"Partition":"[{\"Name\":\"ABC\"},{\"Name\":\"DBC\"}]","id":339}|
|1       |{"Partition":"{\"Name\":\"DDD\"}","id":339}                     |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: is it possible to get result as json instead of string because it is affecting further logic

Comment: root
     |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- entities: json (nullable = true)

Comment: What do you mean by result as json, there is no such Json Type? can you share how your output should look like, or the output schema ?

Comment: it is add an extra " " in "[{\"Name\":\"ABC\"},{\"Name\":\"DBC\"}]" making it as a string

Comment: @shreypavagadhi This is because you have invalid jason again in the partition as well. Where first partition is array type and second is object